# How to execute a javascript function only ONCE on postback without registering

Tags: javascript, vb.net, scriptmanager

I have the following line being ran from Visual Basic:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "populatePayPlan", "populatePayPlan();", True)
```

and it will run that javascript on every postback. I simply only want to run it on a checkbox.CheckChanged just once then never again no matter what. This has to be possible, I'm just missing something?

This was helpful: [Execute javascript function after asp.net postback without Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320999/execute-javascript-function-after-asp-net-postback-without-ajax)

But not exactly what I needed.

Comment: Use a `Session` or `ViewState` key to store whether or not you've registered that script already, and if you have, don't register it?

Answer (score 1):

One trick to make this happen would be to use a closure to ensure the function is only executed once:

```js
var myFunction = (function () {
    var neverCalled = true;
    return function (arg, arg2, arg3) { //Any args for myFunction should be set here
        if(neverCalled) {
            neverCalled = false;
            //Put your function code here.

            return true; //or whatever
        } 
        return false; //or do nothing, or whatever
    };
}());
```

So when the function is "declared", it immediately evaluates the outer function and sets `neverCalled` to `true`, it then returns the inner function (this would be the function you want to execute only once) into the `myFunction` variable (or in your case, you want it to be the `populatePayPlan` variable I think).

The first time you call `myFunction`, it will run, but set `neverCalled` to `false`. Any subsequent executions of the function will skip the block and do nothing. It's a simple and nifty trick that takes advantage of JavaScript's first-class functions and closures aspects and should take care of your needs.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how it should run (note I modified the example code above):

```
myFunction(); //is true;
myFunction(); //is false;
myFunction(); //is false;
```

Just make sure to declare it somewhere where you can access it and don't call it until you need it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For whatever reason I just couldn't get that piece of code to work. It just never executes the code inside the deep nested function. Thanks though!